# Get value in the load file jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, send

I have a jquery function through which I am loading as a light box and sending a value to the loaded file, the code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jq_btn_preview").click(function() {
        gl_popup_id = "#popup_content";
        show_loader();
        $(gl_popup_id).load("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>/preview1.php",{url:'<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>'}, function() {
            //centering with css
            centerPopup();
            //load popup
            loadPopup();
        });
    });
});
```

and in the preview1.php file I want to get the value of the url writing

```
$url = $_GET('url');
```

its showing

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

I can not understand how will i get the value of url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an array not a function, use `$_GET['url']`

Comment: now showing undefined variable url. but I have send url in the line  $(gl_popup_id).load("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>/preview1.php",{url:'<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>'}, function() {}

Comment: @user1412912 can you show the generated code that the browser sees?

Comment: I just write var_dump($_GET); and what is showing I can not copy bcoz it is in a light box. its showing array (size 0)empty

Comment: @user1412912 I mean of this `$(gl_popup_id).load("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>/preview1.php",{url:'<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>'}, function() {`

Comment: $(gl_popup_id).load("http://localhost/mayashop/wp-content/plugins/maya-shop/preview1.php",{url:'http://localhost/mayashop/wp-content/plugins/maya-shop'}, function() {centerPopup();
   
   loadPopup();}

Comment: @user1412912 do you modify `$_GET` in `preview1.php`?

Comment: I use $_REQUEST in the position of $_Get and its working, can not understand why $_GET not working

Comment: @user1412912 you said you changed `$_GET` that's why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

should be `$url = $_GET['url'];` instead of `$url = $_GET('url');`

Comment: now showing undefined index: url. but I have send url in the line  $(gl_popup_id).load("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>/preview1.php",{url:'<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/<?php echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));?>'}, function() {}

Comment: follow Musa question mentioned in comment of his answer.